# MacBook Pro 14’ M1/M2 Pro for docker and virtualization

Tags: apple, macbook

I need to buy a new portable laptop for my uses. Someone gave me an offer on the 2021 MacBook Pro 14 inches with the M1 Pro. I am not far from accepting but the only thing that makes me wait is the fact that I see many posts and everything about docker and virtualization not working well on the Mn chips.

Is it that bad and how did the situation evolve since 2021-2022? Because I see many different other posts that says that some bugs have been fixed, some that say that it does not work and others etc.

If it is that bad do you think that it is even better to consider a custom MacBook Pro config with an Intel processor? Or will it still work?

For info, I use docker for some software projects that use some images like redis, celery, Postgres… do you think that it will be adapted?

PS. I originally wanted a MacBook over a Windows and Linux with M1/M2 Pro chip because I also want to use it for running editing images and videos with software like Lightroom, Photoshop, Premier and also to have the ability to create iOS apps.

Comment: The biggest concern is that all of the docker containers you'll run have to be ARM versions, which might be fine if you're building things on the M1 in the first place. Apparently docker can use QEMU virtualization to run x86 images too but that's probably not going to suddenly get better for an obsolete apple chip; It is still slow.

Comment: @Romen ok thanks for your reply ! But then do you think that it is a sufficient reason to cancel and look for another machine ?

Comment: Potentially. I'd say it depends on which you value more:  x86-based virtualization/containers, or iOS app creation. You should choose accordingly.